# Is localization of a prime ideal still a prime ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Im still new to the topic so this question might seem trivial. But I hope if someone can help explaining to me if a prime ideal $P$ of a domain $A$ is still a prime ideal $P_s$ in the localization $A_s$. Also, is the converse still true?

I actually dont have a reference for this, it's just a question I'm asking myself.

Comment: Is $s$ an arbitrary multiplicative set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Note that $P_s$ being prime is equivalent to $A_s/P_s$ being a domain, and localization commutes with taking quotients, i.e. $A_s/P_s\cong (A/P)_{\bar s}$ where $\bar s$ is the image of $s$ in $A/P$. Thus if $P$ is prime we have $A/P$ is a domain so $A_s/P_s$ is a domain. However, the converse only holds if you assume $s\notin P$ (or if $s$ represents a set, $s\cap P=\emptyset$), as otherwise $A/P$ may not be a domain but $\bar s$ is (or contains) a zero-divisor so $(A/P)_{\bar s}$ may be a domain.